# how programmatically add imageview under other imageview

Tags: android, gridview, imageview, adapter

Hi I have custom adapter which add ti gridview image

[image]

adapter code

```
public View getView(int position,  View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams((tools.getWidth(mContext) - 30) / 3, (tools.getWidth(mContext) - 30) / 3));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        //    imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageBitmap(static_file[position]);
        imageView.setTag(p[position]);

        return imageView;
    }
```

In minimap I have image

[image: play button]

Help me please how I can programmatically add 2-rd image in 1-st[image: final image]

Comment: Maybe you should just save that image as .png ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom layout,

```
<RelativeLayout>
     <ImageView> containing the image you want
     <ImageView> the 2nd image having centerInParent=true
</RelativeLayout>
```

Refer to this
[Custom Adapter for List View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166497/custom-adapter-for-list-view)

Comment: I have only this layout

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridview2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:numColumns="3"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp" />

Answer (score 0):

There is no way simply because your "transparent background" isn't transparent at all. It's just a part of the image, you should remove it as if it was white color, i've made it for, download this image and use it[image]